# Exact match in google search

Tags: search

I am trying to make an application which find all the copied code in a project.
But basically my question is purely related to google search.
I made a search for the keyword "public void bubbleSort(int[] arr){"
and [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=public%20void%20bubbleSort%28int%5B%5D%20arr%29%7B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr#q=public%20void%20bubbleSort%28int%5B%5D%20arr%29%7B&client=firefox-a&hs=dU8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&ei=Mj3qUZ-DNouIrAfNkIHQBA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bmk&fp=b49bbf8e99bfcc5f&biw=1366&bih=664) was the result.

In the first page of search results, only the last url makes a perfect match with my keyword.
Can i tell google with some search keywords so that it will give more importance to pages with an exact match of my search keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+"public void bubbleSort(int[] arr){"

the plus sign means to include this term no matter what. the quotes turn the loosely coupled words into a single term.

for a full list of Google syntax operators:

`[web]:` https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

although the plus sign, +, is no longer an available Google search filter, you can use quotes, or after running the query selecting Search Tools and then verbatim under the All Results drop down.

You can also search the Google code archives, https://code.google.com/ or try some of the other code search engines around the Internet.